# Oracle rds db instance creation and cross region replication using terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am applying above `terraform` file and I am getting tow time the same error below error;

1. I got an error line 37 `source_db_instance_identifier = aws_db_instance.main.identifier`.
2. I got an error line 74 `source_db_instance_identifier = aws_db_instance.main.identifier`.

Do you have any advice ?

```
Error: Unsupported argument
│
│   on main.tf line 37, in resource "aws_db_instance" "replica":
│   37:   source_db_instance_identifier = aws_db_instance.main.identifier
│
│ An argument named "source_db_instance_identifier" is not expected here.
╵
╷
│ Error: Unsupported argument
│
│   on main.tf line 74, in resource "aws_db_instance" "replica_us_west":
│   74:   source_db_instance_identifier = aws_db_instance.main.identifier
│
│ An argument named "source_db_instance_identifier" is not expected here.
```

This is my main.tf

```
provider "aws" {
 region     = "us-east-1"
}

resource "aws_db_instance" "main" {
  identifier             = "my-oracle-instance"
  allocated_storage      = 100
  storage_type           = "gp2"
  engine                 = "oracle-ee"

  engine_version = "19.0.0.0.ru-2021-07.rur-2021-07.r1"
  instance_class         = "db.m5.large"
  username               = "admin"
  password               = "password" # Replace with your secure password
  publicly_accessible    = false
  skip_final_snapshot    = true
  vpc_security_group_ids = ["sg-0afeaf6497b1f3364"]
  parameter_group_name = "default.oracle-ee-19.0"
    
  tags = {
    Name = "mydb"
  }
}
    
resource "aws_db_instance" "replica" {
  for_each               = { replica1 = 1 }  # You can adjust the count or add more replicas as needed
  identifier             = "my-oracle-replica-${each.key}"
  source_db_instance_identifier = aws_db_instance.main.identifier
  engine                 = "oracle-ee"
  engine_version = "19.0.0.0.ru-2021-07.rur-2021-07.r1"
  instance_class         = "db.m5.large"
  username               = "admin"
  password               = "password" # Replace with your secure password
  publicly_accessible    = false
  skip_final_snapshot    = true
  vpc_security_group_ids = ["sg-0afeaf6497b1f3364"]
  parameter_group_name = "default.oracle-ee-19.0"
    
  tags = {
    Name = "mydb-replica-${each.key}"
  }
 }
 
# Define the provider for us-west-1 region
   
provider "aws" {
 alias      = "us_west"
 region     = "us-west-1"
}
    
resource "aws_db_instance" "replica_us_west" {
  provider               = aws.us_west
  for_each               = { replica1 = 1 }  # Adjust count or add more replicas as needed
  identifier             = "my-oracle-replica-us-west-${each.key}"
  source_db_instance_identifier = aws_db_instance.main.identifier
  engine                 = "oracle-ee"

  engine_version = "19.0.0.0.ru-2021-07.rur-2021-07.r1"
  instance_class         = "db.m5.large"
  username               = "admin"
  password               = "password" # Replace with your secure password
  publicly_accessible    = false
  skip_final_snapshot    = true
  vpc_security_group_ids = ["sg-034dc2c037d48ebbc"]
  parameter_group_name = "default.oracle-ee-19.0"
    
  tags = {
    Name = "mydb-replica-us-west-${each.key}"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on terraform documentation, you need to use `[replicate_source_db` argument][1](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/db_instance#replicate_source_db):

> `replicate_source_db` - (Optional) Specifies that this resource is a Replicate database, and to use this value as the source database. This correlates to the identifier of another Amazon RDS Database to replicate (if replicating within a single region) or ARN of the Amazon RDS Database to replicate (if replicating cross-region).

Based on the code you have provided, to me it seems (since you are doing a cross-region replication) that even if you provide this argument, your code will not work, as for cross-region the DB ARN is required. So, for the same region replication, the `identifier` attribute will work, but for cross-region, you need the ARN. I would expect something like this to work:

```
provider "aws" {
 region     = "us-east-1"
}

resource "aws_db_instance" "main" {
  identifier             = "my-oracle-instance"
  allocated_storage      = 100
  storage_type           = "gp2"
  engine                 = "oracle-ee"

  engine_version = "19.0.0.0.ru-2021-07.rur-2021-07.r1"
  instance_class         = "db.m5.large"
  username               = "admin"
  password               = "password" # Replace with your secure password
  publicly_accessible    = false
  skip_final_snapshot    = true
  vpc_security_group_ids = ["sg-0afeaf6497b1f3364"]
  parameter_group_name = "default.oracle-ee-19.0"
    
  tags = {
    Name = "mydb"
  }
}
    
resource "aws_db_instance" "replica" {
  for_each               = { replica1 = 1 }  # You can adjust the count or add more replicas as needed
  identifier             = "my-oracle-replica-${each.key}"
  source_db_instance_identifier = aws_db_instance.main.identifier
  engine                 = "oracle-ee"
  engine_version = "19.0.0.0.ru-2021-07.rur-2021-07.r1"
  instance_class         = "db.m5.large"
  username               = "admin"
  password               = "password" # Replace with your secure password
  publicly_accessible    = false
  skip_final_snapshot    = true
  vpc_security_group_ids = ["sg-0afeaf6497b1f3364"]
  parameter_group_name = "default.oracle-ee-19.0"
    
  tags = {
    Name = "mydb-replica-${each.key}"
  }
 }

# Define the provider for us-west-1 region
   
provider "aws" {
 alias      = "us_west"
 region     = "us-west-1"
}
resource "aws_db_instance" "replica_us_west" {
  provider = aws.us_west
  for_each = { replica1 = 1 } # Adjust count or add more replicas as needed
  identifier = "my-oracle-replica-us-west-${each.key}"
  replicate_source_db = aws_db_instance.main.arn
  engine = "oracle-ee"
  engine_version = "19.0.0.0.ru-2021-07.rur-2021-07.r1"
  instance_class = "db.m5.large"
  username = "admin"
  password = "MyPassword123" # Replace with your secure password
  publicly_accessible = false
  skip_final_snapshot = true
  vpc_security_group_ids = ["sg-034dc2c037d48ebbc"]
  parameter_group_name = "default.oracle-ee-19.0"

  tags = {
    Name = "mydb-replica-us-west-${each.key}"
  }
}
```

The [`source_db_instance_identifier` argument](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/db_instance#source_db_instance_identifier) is used within the `restore_to_point_in_time` block, so it cannot be standalone.